# What data is actually stored in a B-tree database in CouchDB?

Tags: indexing, locking, couchdb, time-complexity, b-tree

I'm wondering what is actually stored in a CouchDB database B-tree? The [CouchDB: The Definitive Guide](http://books.couchdb.org/relax/) tells that a database B-tree is used for append-only operations and that a database is stored in a single B-tree (besides per-view B-trees).

So I guess the data items that are appended to the database file are **revisions** of documents, not the whole documents:

```
            +---------|### ...  
            |           |
   +------|###|------+     ... ---+
   |        |        |            |
+------+ +------+ +------+     +------+
| doc1 | | doc2 | | doc1 | ... | doc1 |
| rev1 | | rev1 | | rev2 |     | rev7 |
+------+ +------+ +------+     +------+
```

Is it true?

If it *is* true, then how the current revision of a document is determined based on such a B-tree?

Doesn't it mean, that CouchDB needs a separate "view" database for indexing *current revisions* of documents to preserve O(log n) access? Wouldn't it lead to race conditions while building such an index? (as far as I know, CouchDB uses no write locks).

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'erlang'?

Comment: @Zed Yep, it's irrelevant here.

Comment: CouchDB definitely *does* serialize writes. There is one Erlang process for writing data to the file. All writes must go through that process's mailbox which Erlang of course serializes.

Comment: It is tagged Erlang because Erlang is used to trivially enforce coherency in the DB file via the mechanism I just described :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database file on disk is append-only; however the B-tree is conceptually modified in-place. When you update a document,

1. Its leaf node is written (via append to the DB file)
2. Its parent node is re-written to reference the new leaf (via append of course)
3. Repeat step 2 until you update the root node

When the root node is written, that is effectively when the newer revision is "committed." To find a document, you start at the end of the file, get the root node, and work down to your doc id. The latest revision will always be accessible this way.

Comment: It's still unclear to me when the algorithm for determining the winning revision (http://books.couchdb.org/relax/reference/conflict-management) comes into play during the current document revision lookup. If the user is reading the document with the key ID1, then according to the scheme you've described he will get the **latest written** revision (thanks for your point on serializing writes using an Erlang process), **not the winning one**.

Comment: I guess I need to dig into the source code. It's quite observable: 18 KLOC.

Comment: The conflict management algorithm decides which order to store them in (i.e. does this get rev 4 and that get rev 5 or vice versa ). A simple lookup by ID always fetches the latest revision stored. In this example, revision 5 would be the "winner." The application may want to merge the conflict more meaningfully by creating a revision 6 that is the sum of 4 and 5.

Comment: Jason, can you provide more information on steps 2,3 or point to a link that describes it in detail? I am curious if only the document's parent node is rewritten after the new revision or if the entire B+ tree (inner nodes only) is rewritten, in reverse order, after the end of each document revision. So in the case of a DB with a billion documents that 3-levels deeps, if I update 1 document, is that new revision written out, then level 2 of the B+ tree (with millions of references) written then level 1 of the B+ tree (with 10,000s of references) written right after it? Seems untenable...

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB does not store diffs. When you update a document, it appends the whole new document with a new _rev and the same _id as the old version. The old version is removed during compaction.

Comment: Yes, CouchDB doesn't store diffs. My question is how does it store documents internally in order to make both write-only save operations *and* current version retrievals, without locks?